# How change the mount point on an external hdd that has data on it, without deleting any data?

Tags: hard-disk, data

I need to change the mountpoint from "/media" to "/mnt" on an external hdd that has data that can not be deleted.

I read that I can create a directory using "sudo mkdir", but that is all I have found so far.

THE GOAL: "sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdxx /mnt"

Thanks.

Comment: You can `sudo mkdir /mnt`, can `umount /media` and do your `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdxx /mnt`, so what is the question left to ask? The data on the disk is not affected by remounting.

Comment: @Philippos Thanks. Well, how to get the new "/mnt" directory connected to the hdd.

Comment: @Philippos Yes, just mounting it with the 'mnt ending worked. I had no idea it was that easy! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the directory "/mnt" allowed a new mountpoint to mount the hdd to. The directory "/mnt" was already there, but if you need to create it, just do "sudo mkdir /mnt" and the directory will now show up in the filesystem directories.

Simply, mounting the hdd as "/mnt" instead of "/media" allowed me to change the mountpoint for the hdd. `sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdxx /mnt`. This creates a 2nd directory for mounting a hdd to; thus, 2 hdd's can be mounted to the filesystem.